# Xamarin no longer debugging my app

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, emulation

I've been working on a Xamarin project for a few days and have been testing it fine, but today it has suddenly stopped allowing me to debug the app, either via Live Player, or by connecting my smart phone via USB.

The only error I am getting, as far as I can see, is

> Failed to debug your app

I've not got a way of testing it on iOS devices, but the built-in Windows Phone emulator runs the app fine, albeit with an error in my code popping up now and then.

What could be causing the Android version to stop debugging, or how do I at least fix it?

Comment: One option that might help is deleting .vs folder.

Comment: delete bin and obj folders, build every project one by one to see which one fails, then try to compile

Comment: @Vahid where is that? I can't find it anywhere

Comment: @David .vs is a hidden directory in the root of your solution directory.

Comment: @Vahid nope, still no change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a proper solution, but I uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio. This seems to have fixed the problem, but I've still no idea why it stopped working in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of steps that can help with that issue:

1. Clean the solution and exit visual studio
2. manually delete the .vs folder in your solution directory
3. Delete the /obj and /bin folders in your shared code, and in each project for the platforms you are using
4. if you are developing for iOS, sometimes it helps to restart your mac
5. Start Visual Studio
6. Rebuild your shared code project
7. Rebuild every native project

Beyond that also make sure that you are using the latest versions of Visual Studio, Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms on all your computers, and that the nuGet Packages your project is using are at the very same version each in shared and native code

Also check, if your app isn't throwing an unexpected exception during its initialization. Especially if not caught, it can happen that your app crashes before your code gets executed at all.

In addition you may find further information about what is going on at Help -> Xamarin -> Open logs or in the device management in XCode (iOS only)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

1. Close visual studio if open.
2. Open App Data and then go to 
   (a) Local\Xamarin 
   (B) Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android
3. Empty these folders.
4. Open your project and then try to build your application.