# How do I debug on Android

Tags: xamarin.android

My device is Samsung A51. I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and perhaps a week or two earlier (don't recall exactly) debugging on the Android was no problem. Now, when I click on Debug menu option F5 Start Debugging, the app refreshes on the Android but there are no breakpoints.

I found this:

[Xamarin no longer debugging my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50859736/xamarin-no-longer-debugging-my-app)

and tried the solutions offered there to no avail. I haven't (to my knowledge) made any changes to Debug Options. The code does not break when it should.

Thanks.
RON

Comment: For some reason I had to have a question Title like this. If I mentioned Xamarin, I couldn't post. ALSO, to note, Dev Mode is on. And the same issue occurs if I run the emulator. And what happens on the Debug menu is that it shows not in use (not greyed out like when its debugging. Apologies for not explaining this correctly)

Comment: What have you tried doing so far, Have you tried removing bin and obj? Have you tried restarting VS or your computer in general after updating the VS?

Comment: Yes, I removed bin and obj and vs, closed down VS. Restarted, all of that. Interestingly, the emulator works just fine when I'm not on Samsung Debugging. I never could get that to work. But still, no breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

First, thanks to all who helped (and even on the previous question by someone else). It was a setting in VS, Project Properties->Android Options->Enable developer instrumentation. It wasn't set. Now it is all is good in the world.